# Play On HD Mini won't connect to home network, please help

Tags: wireless-networking, router, streaming

I bought a streamer, "Play on hd mini". It works fine with media from USB or an external hard-drive, but I can't connect it to the network. I have a wireless network, using an Edimax 802.11 g broadband router and two or three computer connected to it wirelessly, and one connected through a cable. There are several shared directories on that network.

When trying to setup wireless access on my streamer, I have a few options:
1) Infrastructure (AP)
2) peer to peer (AD Hoc)
3) WPS (AP)

I choose the first option. From there I can see all the wireless networks around. I choose my network and give him my password. Then I have two options: either DHCP IP, or FIX IP. the option of DHCP IP doesn't seem to work, so I manually put in IP address, Subnet mask, etc. It makes an attempt to connect, and then says wireless setup is "on", and shows signal strength and IP.

But I still can't access the web, or any computer on my network.  What should I do?